# Pathfinding with teleporters

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, robotics, cartesian

I'm working on a project with a virtual robot (Turtles in the ComputerCraft mod for Minecraft), where the robot would be in a maze of tunnels and have to navigate around in them. The world is conveniently already divided into tiles (a 2D Cartesian graph of them, with a boolean passable/nonpassable value for each), and the robot building the tunnels will map them as he goes.

In addition, there are teleporter "shortcuts" scattered around in areas where robots need to get between them quickly.

The question is: What's the best way to have the robot pathfind to his destination? How would the system identify areas that need teleporters? A* is the most famous algorithm, but are there others that might suit the application better? Please keep in mind that I have very little experience with pathfinding algorithms, so you might have to break things down into base terms for me to understand. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not try A* first and see how it performs?

Comment: I certainly could, but I'd assume A* doesn't take "shortcuts" like the teleporters into account without a hack. I'll have to look into how to algorithm works a little bit more.

Comment: What hack? I think A* can work with zero-length edges just fine. I'm curious.

Comment: Hmm. I'll do some research and write an implementation. Might work out of the box, who knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem with using A* is finding an [admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) for your problem.  Fortunately, this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428389/238419).

> How would the system identify areas that need teleporters?

That depends on where the turtle is actually moving to/from.  If he's always moving to/from the same start/end points, the answer is trivial:  add teleports at the start and finish.  For more complicated setups, my guess would be that this is NP-hard; if true, you'll have to look into [global-optimization strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) *(or just try a bunch of random positions and take the best one)*.